# laravel retrieving specific data

Tags: laravel

im trying output all requests made by a user and display it in a profile page in laravel project,
in my home controller i have this function

```
public function profile()
{
    $requests = Requests::where('userid', '{{ Auth::user()->userid }}')->get();
    return view('profile');
}
```

and this outputs this message:

FatalErrorException in E:\xampp\htdocs\test1\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php line 31:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Requests' not found

(line 31 is the top line of the function above)

this is my profile.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Profile: {{ Auth::user()->f_name }}</h1></div>

            <div class="panel-body">
               @foreach ($requests as $requests)
                <ul>

                    <h4>Title: {{$requests->r_title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Author: {{$requests->r_author}}</h4>
                    <h4>Year: {{$requests->r_year}}</h4>
                    <h4>Condition: {{$requests->r_condition}}</h4>
                    <br/>
                </ul>

                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

this is the Request.php page in the app folder

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Requests extends Model
{

protected $primaryKey = 'requestid';

 protected $fillable = [
   'userid', 'f_name', 'l_name', 'r_title', 'r_year', 'r_author', 'r_condition'
];


}
```

Comment: What code do you have on HomeController? May be you missed to import the Requests class.

Comment: Your file name needs to be same as class name.  So if you actually have `class Requests` inside a file named `Request.php`, that class would not be included in your autoloader.  If you are still having issues, follow the advice of other answers in here and ensure you are properly namespacing and important that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this. Also verify if the user table has `userid` since it's `id` by default unless you've changed.

```
public function profile()
{
    $requests = \App\Requests::where('userid', auth()->user()->userid)->get();

    return view('profile')->with(['requests' => $requests]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your model to controller by:

```
use App\Requests;
```

Other way is change `profile()` method to:

```
public function profile()
{
    $requests = \App\Requests::where('userid', \Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('profile');
}
```

next you can pass `$requests` to the view by:

```
return view('profile', [
    'requests' => \App\Requests::where('userid', \Auth::user()->id)->get(),
]);
```

Now you have access to $requests in your blade file. :)